# jersey/jaxb unmarshalling a java object, but fields not populated

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I have a Jersey server side code which takes a Java object as a body parameter. This Java object lets say `Preferences` is defined as below.

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "preferences", namespace = "http://arjun.test.com/tests/1.0")
 public class Preferences {

    String field1;
    String field2;

    public Preferences() {
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "field-1", namespace = "http://arjun.test.com/tests/1.0")
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
       this.field1 = field1;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

My problem is: while sending the data from client I am populating both fields, but somehow in the server the first field value is always null, if I change the field1 XML annotation to the same as field2, then it works fine.

Can someone please let me know what mistake am I doing.

The Jersey server method is producing and consuming the JSON objects.

Comment: if i use the first field with the following xml annotation it works @XmlElement(name = "field1") .i.e with out "-" in name. This means anything???

Comment: did you try adding @XmlElement(name = "field-2", namespace = "http://arjun.test.com/tests/1.0")
 to getField2?

Comment: yes it didn't help, in that case even field2 is null.

Comment: Are you sure you set field2 value? try to figure out the diff between field1 and field2, maybe in another part of your code. Did you tried without "namespace" parameter in XmlRootElement and XmlElement?

Comment: There is no other difference, except the name parameter in the xml annotation. yes i have removed the namespace and tried to no vain.

Comment: How are you sending the data from the client?